Scrolling the modal window in React
I created a component in React that I use as a modal window that opens when you click on a button, but I don't know how to make it scroll when it opens, and not the main window.
import close from '/close.png'; 
import add from '/add1.png'; 
import './Modal.css';  
import MainButton2 from '../Button/MainButton2'

import { useState, useRef } from "react";
export default function  Modal ({ isOpen, onClose }, props) {
    if (!isOpen) return null;
    return (
        <div className="modal-overlay">
    
            <div className="modal-content">
               <div className='thefirstrow'>
                <div className='newpod'>jasjssj</div> 
                <img className='close' src={close} alt='user'   style={{ cursor: 'pointer'  }}  onClick={onClose}/>
                </div>
             
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

Modal.css
.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2000;

}

.modal-content {
  position: absolute; 
  background: white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 64vw;
  height: 630px;
  z-index: 1001;
  margin-top: 100px; 
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
}

that's how it opens in the main window:
 <Modal isOpen={isModalOpenPodcast} onClose={() => setIsModalOpenPodcast(false)} />

You are not giving enough information about your problem. It would be good if you could provide the code from your Modals.css file as well

are you saying that the background moves when you are trying to scroll just the modal?  both are scrolling?  the modal won't scroll?

only the main window scrolls

If you're trying to make the content in the modal scrollable just add "overflow: scroll" to your ".modal-content" style class.
.modal-content {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 40px;
  width: 64vw;
  height: 630px;
  z-index: 1001;
  margin-top: 100px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  overflow: scroll;
}

And make your content large enough so you can scroll.
.newpod {
  height: 2000px;
}

